# How to access the index of tableview to next vc

Tags: ios, swift

Task is to show cricket players names and their images in first vc inside tableview.
When I click on tableview didselect row that particular image and their name will be shown in a second VC.

And in the second VC there is a previous and next button; when clicking on previous button and next button, data should change based on the index from the first VC.

In the second VC, how do I show the previous and next data when click on these two buttons based on the index from first VC?

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewPlayer: UITableView!

    var arrPlayers = ["Dhoni","Sachin","Virat","Raina"]
    var arrPlayerImage = ["Dhoni","Sachin","Virat","Raina"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrPlayers.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewPlayer.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayersTableViewCell")as! PlayersTableViewCell
        cell.lblPlayerName.text = arrPlayers[indexPath.row]
        cell.imgPlayer.image = UIImage(named: arrPlayerImage[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DetailsVC")as? DetailsVC
        vc?.playerImage =  UIImage(named: arrPlayerImage[indexPath.row])!
        vc?.playerName = arrPlayers[indexPath.row]
        vc?.currentIndex = indexPath.row
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
  //  ios swift how to send the data from didselect row to next vc
}
```

```
import UIKit

class DetailsVC: UIViewController {
    
    var playerImage = UIImage()
    var playerName = ""
    var currentIndex : Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewPlayer: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblPlayerInfo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPrevious: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnNext: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lblPlayerInfo.text = playerName
        imageViewPlayer.image = playerImage
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func btnPrevious(_ sender: UIButton) {
//        currentIndex -= 1
//        lblPlayerInfo.text = playerName
//        imageViewPlayer.image = playerImage
//        if currentIndex <= 0{
//            currentIndex = 0
//        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnNext(_ sender: UIButton) {
//        currentIndex += 1
//        lblPlayerInfo.text = playerName
//        imageViewPlayer.image = playerImage
//        if currentIndex == 3{
//            currentIndex = 0
//        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

pass the arrPlayers array to DetailsVC,

```
class DetailsVC: UIViewController {

   var currentIndex  = 0
    var arrPlayers = [String]()

   @IBOutlet weak var imageViewPlayer: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var lblPlayerInfo: UILabel!

   var playerName = ""

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showThePlayerName(name: arrPlayers[currentIndex])
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
        
    }

    @IBAction func btnPrevious(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let getName = arrPlayers.prev(item: playerName){
            showThePlayerName(name: getName)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func btnNext(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let getName = arrPlayers.next(item: playerName){
            showThePlayerName(name: getName)
        }
    }

func showThePlayerName(name: String){
       playerName =  name
       lblPlayerInfo.text = name
      imageViewPlayer.image = UIImage(named: name)
}

}
```

use the extension for get the next or previous element

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func next(item: Element) -> Element? {
        if let index = self.firstIndex(of: item), index + 1 <= self.count {
            return index + 1 == self.count ? self[0] : self[index + 1]
        }
        return nil
    }

    func prev(item: Element) -> Element? {
        if let index = self.firstIndex(of: item), index >= 0 {
            return index == 0 ? self.last : self[index - 1]
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and finally pass the index from viewcontroller as like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DetailsVC")as? DetailsVC
        vc?.arrPlayers = arrPlayers
        vc?.currentIndex = indexPath.row
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of implementing what you want. The easiest will be passing array of names and images to the `DetailsVC`, so that you can change the name and images when next and/or previous buttons tapped with according index.

Another easy approach is keeping the reference to the list view controller in `DetailsVC` (`ViewController` in your case, like `var listVC: ViewController?`) and implement function like `func playerInfoForIndex(_ index: Int) -> (name: String, image: String)` in your `ViewController` and call that function whenever next or previous buttons are pressed in `DetailsVC` with proper index.

Ideally, it's better to have a protocol for navigation between name and images (data), but I think that's a future read for you, you can take a look [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html).

You should experiment more before you find the best path for you. Good luck!